# Oracle Report Generated PDF is not closing the CreatorDate Bracket in 1 0 obj example /CreatorDate (

Tags: node.js, pdf

I am using FS to read the pdf then replace the CreatorDate>
var fs = require('fs');

```
fs.readFile('./pdf/0219.PDF', 'utf8', function (err,data) {
  if (err) {
    return console.log(err);
  }

  var result = data.replace(/'CreatorDate \('/g, 'Test');

  fs.writeFile('./pdf/0219.PDF', result, 'utf8', function (err) {
     if (err) return console.log(result, err);
  });

});
```

>

Comment: Here is the object %PDF-1.1
1 0 obj
<<
/Creator (Developer 2000)
/CreatorDate (
/Author (Oracle Reports)
/Producer (Oracle PDF driver)
/Title (./pdf/0219.PDF)
>>
endobj

Comment: What is your actual question? This looks more like you'd want to submit an Oracle Reports bug report..

Comment: Can I replace or remove the CreatorDate with string replace?

Comment: First of all don't use `utf8`. PDF is *not* UTF-8 encoded text, PDF is a binary format. Thus, essentially arbitrary byte sequences can occur in it. Not all byte sequences can be UTF-8 decoded and, therefore, some byte sequences will be replaced by a replacement character. This replacement, of course, cannot be undone when writing the file back, so it will damage the PDF. Use an encoding which has a single character for each byte value. Whether treating as text will do other damage, I don't know as I don't know JavaScript characteristics in this regard.